# How can I click on radiobutton through angular storybook interaction?

Tags: angular, angular8, storybook

I need to click on radio button option while adding its interaction via play function in storybook story.
I have tried using below 2 approaches of providing with radio button value with unique role and second using common radio button role and selecting value.
storybook function code:

```
  play: async ({ _, canvasElement, step }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);

    //  await fireEvent.click(canvas.getByRole('TRAINING'));
    //  await userEvent.click(canvas.getByRole('issueType'));
      const submitradioButton = canvas.getByRole('issueType');

      await userEvent.selectOptions(submitradioButton, 'TRAINING');

    });
  },
```

html code

```
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="issueType" role="issueType">
          <mat-radio-button value="TRAINING" role="TRAINING">Insurance
             </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="FOLLOWUP" role="FOLLOWUP">System
            </mat-radio-button>       
        </mat-radio-group>
```